# Are all attributes of an object evaluated at the same time in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, object

Let's take this code:

```js
{ a: Date.now(), b: Date.now() }
```

It returns: `{ a: 1664294035466, b: 1664294035466 }`

Can I be sure that the keys `a` and `b` will always have the same value?

Comment: No: `i = 0; obj = { a: i++, b: i++ }`

Comment: If you want them reliably initialized to the same value, then use a temporary `const t = Date.now(); let obj = {a: t, b: t}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. `Date.now` returns the current time at the exact moment it is called. This code will call it twice, and it's possible (with luck) that the timer ticks over to the next millisecond in between the calls.